# WSO2 EMM - android device enrollment

Tags: android, wso2-iot

i am trying the EMM version 2.2.0, but i cannot enroll an android device in COPE mode.
I have a message which says to install the "wso2 system app" but i don't know what it is.
Can you help me with this ?

By the way, enrollment in BYOD mode works fine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the android agent, there is another system app introduced to provide advanced control over Android devices. You will find the article [1] helpful in enrolling an android device in COPE mode.

[1] - http://wso2.com/library/articles/2016/07/article-advanced-handling-of-cope-android-devices-using-wso2-enterprise-mobility-manager/

Answer (score 0):

COPE mode needs system app which need to be run as root to perform some special system tasks. So you need to install the system app along with the agent app.